# WebStorm tsconfig.json appears to not update the correct files

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm

I am developing a node.js application using TypeScript.

I've created a TypeScript file in the root folder of my project. I run `tsconfig` and it appears to update the `dist` folder. However, when I run the app, I am getting an error indicating a function is not defined.

Here is where things get confusing: there seems to be older versions of the `.js` and `.map` files in my `src` folder in the same directories as my source files with the same names. This `.js` file seems to have an older version of the file missing the necessary functions (class methods), different from the current versions in my `/dist` folder.

At the end of the day, I am trying to run the debugger on the files in my `/dist` folder and set breakpoints over in my `/src` TypeScript files.

This is a sample of the file structure I am seeing in my `/src` folder (this js file is not current):

[image]

Here is a sample of the file structure of my `/dist` folder where the transpiled js code resides:

[image]

Also, here are the debugger settings for the web app (rest) portion of the project:

[image]

Finally, here is a sample of the `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "types": ["reflect-metadata"],
    "lib": ["ES6"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src/",
    "noLib": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "node_modules/@types"
  ]
}
```

1. I would like to understand what is wrong, causing it to read the wrong js files, instead of the ones in the `/dist` folder?
2. What can I do to fix this to point to the `/dist` folder. I thought the debugger settings I setup would do that, but this does not appear to be the case.

Update: I deleted the .js files that were generated in the src folder and they eventually returned back to the folder and once again, they were not current after making other changes.  I am not sure what is generating these files; is it a setting in webstorm or is it in tsconig.json?

Something else doesn't look right.  When I opened one of the files in the dist folder, I found the following code instead of JS code:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
//# sourceMappingURL=group.js.map
```

This is not what I was expecting, as I was expecting to see the transpiled js code.

Comment: If you delete those `.js` files in `src/` folder, do they appear again?

Comment: They do not, but now I am getting "Cannot find module" errors, which is preventing the app. from starting.  Also, when I scroll to the bottom of the .js file in the /dist folder I see the following: //# sourceMappingURL=group.js.map.  Don't know if this helps.

Comment: That is another error. The `//# sourceMappingURL=group.js.map` is the comment which is appended to the end of a javascript file to enable sourcemaping.

Comment: It seems like the sourceMappingUrl path is incorrect.  When I tried to delete the .map file located in the /src folder and it told me that it was being referenced and it pointed to the sourceMappingUrl over in the /dist folder.

Comment: It seems like it is expecting there to be a .js file in the /src folder that corresponds to the .ts file.  When the .js file and .map are over in the /dist folder.  This is confusing.

Comment: Can you try compile your project outside WebStorm and post the messages? If you don't know how, just call `tsc` inside the folder of your project.

Comment: I ran it from the webstorm terminal screen.  I received several "Cannot find module ....." errors, though I can see them listed in the dependencies for my package.json file.  I also ran npm install again to be sure they were added.  The weird thing is that I am not seeing these when I run by clicking on the tsconfig.json file and choosing "tyoescript compile".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149218/discussion-between-lilezek-and-user1790300).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `src` in your includes and in your `rootDir`, everything should be declared relative to `rootDir`, but in this case you likely don't need the includes or excludes since you're including everything in `src` anyway. The `compileOnSave` option is what is generating the files as you delete them because a `watcher` has been set up to do so. You're also mixing your `target` and `lib` javascript versions.

You do not need to explicitly exclude `@types` if you are using the `types` property already.

> If types is specified, only packages listed will be included.

Here's a cleaned up config you can try

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "types": ["reflect-metadata"],
    "lib": ["ES5"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "noLib": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```